# Blazor WebAssembly: send Float32Array from javascript to .NET

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

This is my JS:

```
window.testSendFloatArray = (obj) => {

    var iterable = function* () { yield* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; }();
    var float32 = new Float32Array(iterable); 

    obj.invokeMethodAsync('SendFloatArray', float32);
}
```

This is the C#:

```
[JSInvokable]
public Task SendFloatArray(JsonElement wtf)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And this is how I call `testSendFloatArray` from C#:

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("testSendFloatArray", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
```

I set breakpoints everywhere and everything is wired up properly, but when the `SendFloatArray` gets called, I have no idea what to do with `wtf`. The only reason I know it's a `JsonElement` is because I originally had it is type `object` and did a `wtf.GetType().Name` on it.

When I serialize the value with `JsonSerializer.Serialize(wtf)` it returns this:

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6}
```

After an hour of playing with it, I figured out I could call `EnumerateObject` (`EnumerateArray` failed) on it:

```
[JSInvokable]
public Task SendFloatArray(JsonElement wtf)
{
    var myArray = wtf.EnumerateObject().Select(x => x.Value.GetDouble()).ToArray();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But there must be a better way to do this, correct? How do I cleanly get an array of primitives to a C# assembly from Javascript?

Comment: Did you end up finding something better to do than using JsonElement?

Comment: @Ovenkoek -- Nope, never did. Code still looks like this till this day. But, this post is pretty old, so I don't know if the Bl@zor team came up with anything better since then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I googled around a bit but couldn't find anything.
I did change the parameter to a "Dictionary<int,float>" instead and then you can simply do dict.Values.ToArray(), which is a bit better but still not perfect.

Comment: @Ovenkoek -- I know this is old, but apparently, they fixed it so you can just declare `float[]` as the parameter type on the C# side of things and it will just work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been rectified in recent versions of Blazor. You can just set it to a `float[]` type and it just works.

```cs
[JSInvokable]
public Task SendFloatArray(float[] floatArray)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```